# Determine class type of Generic typed field

Tags: java, generics, reflection, field, nosuchfieldexception

I am getting `NoSuchFieldException` for the following piece of code:

```
public class MultipleSorting<T> extends Observable {
    private SelectItem[] criteria1;
    private SelectItem[] order1;
    private SelectItem[] criteria2;
    private SelectItem[] order2;
    private SelectItem[] criteria3;
    private SelectItem[] order3;

    private T criteriaType;

    private T selectedCriteria1;
    private SortOrder selectedOrder1;
    private T selectedCriteria2;
    private SortOrder selectedOrder2;
    private T selectedCriteria3;
    private SortOrder selectedOrder3;    

    private Boolean[] enabledRows = new Boolean[]{Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE};

    private Boolean addButtonVisible1 = Boolean.TRUE;
    private Boolean addButtonVisible2 = Boolean.FALSE;
    private Boolean addButtonVisible3 = Boolean.FALSE;

    public MultipleSorting() {
        super();
    }

    private Class<T> getCriteriaClass() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = this.getClass().getField("criteriaType");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (Class<T>)field.getType();
    }

    public void addOrRemoveRow(ActionEvent event) {
        // other codes
        Method setSelectedCriteriaMethod = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelectedCriteria" + (index + 1), new Class[]{getCriteriaClass()});  
        // other codes
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I am getting the exception when I invoke the method `getCriteriaClass()`. The `criteriaType` doesn't have any getter and seeter method. Also this field is not initialized. That is why I cannot call `criteriaType.getClass()` as it is throwing `NullPointerException`.

My aim is to determine the class type of `T` and I don't want to pass the class of T in the constructor of this `MultipleSorting` class.

I am unable to understand why I am getting `NoSuchFieldException`. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [JavaDoc of `getField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29), you see the problem:

> *Returns a Field object that reflects the specified **public member field** of the class or interface represented by this Class object.*

You need to use:

```
Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("criteriaType");
```

From the [JavaDoc of`getDeclaredField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) :

> *Returns a Field object that reflects the specified declared field of the class or interface represented by this Class object.*

Note that `getDeclaredField()`, unlike `getField()`, won't find inherited fields.

Comment: This is the best explanation I saw for [tag:nosuchfieldexception]. Although it does not mention that the _reason for this exception_ is mostly a **version mismatch**.