# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am currently using vscode and apache poi, created a program to automatically create a `.xlsx` program and have A1 cell input a String called "Tester", and that error pops up.

Codes in my program:

```
package excel_reader;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelWriter {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        //ExcelReader eR = new ExcelReader();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  // here is the7 line 13
        // first sheet create
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstExcelSheet");
        // first row create - A
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        // first cell create - 1
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0); // A-1
        // give data into A-1 cell
        cell.setCellValue("Tester");

        // Output as an excel file
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Sonic\\Desktop\\book.xlsx"));
        workbook.close();

        // C:\\Users\\Sonic\\Desktop\\book.xlsx
    }
}
```

Error Code:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\excel_reader_v.1_beta1-0> cd 'e:\excel_reader_v.1_beta1-0'; & 'C:\Users\Sonic\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.24.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Users\Sonic\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\bin\java' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Sonic\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_5wuvlu562pjj6rfd2pconxvl4.jar' 'excel_reader.ExcelWriter' 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:161)
        at excel_reader.ExcelWriter.main(ExcelWriter.java:13)
```

pom.xml (`dependency`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Apache POI is new to me, please do help me, I will be very appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please mark the line numbered `18` in your code (file `ExcelWriter.java`). This seems to be the line that causes the exception.

Comment: Any reason for extending ExcelReader?

Comment: I just tried running your code. the only part I changed was removed Excel Reader entirely and then gave path to the file explicitly. It is working fine for me.

Comment: @hc_dev mark the line numbered 18? May I ask what do you mean by marking line number 18? thank you, just confusing.

Comment: @MehulGayate you right, for no reason, I should be double checking it first, but I wonder is it because of extending ExcelReader thus causing the exception? Thank you, I wish that I can understand and remember the mistake that I made to prevent having the same mistake next time, thank you.

Comment: @FlashSonic526 I mean _mark the line_ numbered `18` __by a comment__ like `// here the error was`. And could you please __post the whole [stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)__ including lines starting with `Caused by:`. This helps spotting the error. Besides I have no clue what is class `ExcelReader` (your own class or from POI)? And what does method `getImpoFileLink()` do ? Maybe [edit] your question and post code of this class as well.

Comment: could you share the pom.xml in here? and also, it would be great if you could also put the result of `mvn dependency:tree` in here.

Comment: @kucing_terbang I updated the error code and other stuff, not sure about what is a `mvn dependency:tree`, but updated the error codes, codes, and added the dependency that i used, also, I do not know how to use a dependency or is that how I make a dependency, but I searched it online and that's what it said.

Comment: @FlashSonic526 Have researched, found and totally revised my answer. Now I see your updated question (with POM, finally) - Great, you added everything! From your POM issue and solution are confirmed: only keep the 2 `<dependency>`s with version `4.1.1` (i.e. `poi` and `poi-ooxml`) and remove the rest :-)

Comment: @hc_dev Umm, may you please teach me something about dependency? I still got the same error, and it still doesn't work for me, please do help me, thanks.
ps. I am not sure about the dependency, I just created a file named `pom.xml`,  and found all the dependency stuff thru this website, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi.

Comment: @hc_dev btw, since I do not know much about dependency, therefore, I just follow the instructions where I put the `pom.xml` file into the `lib` folder, is that correct? I also wonder that is dependency = dependency injection? Thank you.

Comment: @hc_dev Also, to make sure that I am following the steps correctly, the only 2 `dependency` I should have are the `poi` and `poi-ooxml`? Right? Also, I did not set a classpath to my `.xml` file, I just leave it in my `lib` folder, please correct me if I am not right, and also, I really appreciated for all who have been trying to help me resolving my problem, thank you. (I replyed to your message in the chat room, please check, tkx.)

Comment: It said that my Maven project is `[Corrupted]` and when I click on it, it said, `Generating Dependency Tree: undefined` what does it mean? Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Cause of `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError`

If you **search StackOverflow for tag [nosuchfieldexception](/questions/tagged/nosuchfieldexception)** you will find a lot of similar questions. Most of them have 2 things in common:

- the error says that a **CONSTANT [field could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16881121/5730279)**
- the cause is that 2 or more [dependencies](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm) (i.e. third-party JAR files) which are related have **different version**.

This **version mismatch** may also cause your error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT

Since the constant [`DEFAULT`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/3.17/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/udf/UDFFinder.html#DEFAULT) of class `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.UDFFinder` existed in versions prior to 3.17, but now (versions 4.0 and newer) has been *deprecated*. Means, it does [not exist in version 4.0](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/udf/UDFFinder.html) and above.

**Problem at runtime:**
If statement `new XSSFWorkbook();` (at line 13) is executed using dependency (JAR) `poi-ooxml`, then it uses a `UDFFinder` of the core dependency (JAR) `poi` and thus tries to find the CONSTANT field `DEFAULT` (which may not be there, since versions mismatch).

So I suppose, your versions of Apache `poi` and `poi-ooxml` are mismatching (not the same level).
See [similar question with *version mismatch* using Apache Poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618369/nosuchfielderror-when-reading-excel-sheet-in-java/37619083#37619083).

#### Solution: matching versions!

If you are using [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), make sure you have these dependencies on your POM:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

At least **both have to be the same version**!

If you are managing your classpath and JARs manually, watch out for the filename of all apache-poi JAR files and make sure the versions are same.

#### Code seems very close to working

If you just want to write your freshly created Excel-Workbook to a file, e.g. `/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx` (on Linux) or `C:/Users/Sonic/MyFirstExcel.xlsx` (on Windows, supposed your Windows-User is `Sonic`) then use this code:

```java
public class ExcelWriter {
    static final String FILE_PATH_LINUX = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";
    static final String FILE_PATH_WIN = "C:/Users/Sonic/MyFirstExcel.xlsx"; // note: replace Window's backslash '\' by either double-backslash '\\' or single forward-slash '/'

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstExcelSheet"); // first sheet create
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0); // first row create - A
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0); // first cell create - A-1        
        cell.setCellValue("Tester"); // give data into A-1 cell

        // Output as an excel file
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH_WIN));
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

**Unclear usage of class `ExcelReader`:**
There is no obvious reason to extend from `ExcelReader`.
Thus and for simplicity you can omit the `extends ExcelReader`, declaration of `ExcelReader eR = new ExcelReader();` and usage `eR.getImpoFileLink()` to get the *file-path*. Otherwise please post the source-code of class `ExcelReader` to your question, to make it a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

**Minimal working solution (above) explained:**
Instead just put a *file-path* to desired folder and file, like constant `FILE_PATH_WIN` here.
I saw [your related question few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484870/exception-in-org-apache-poi), where you did that.

Supposed you fixed your [other issues/questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484870/exception-in-org-apache-poi), as well as resolved the *version-mismatch* with POI dependencies here, the solution given above should compile and write out the desired Excel workbook (.xlsx) with sheet `FirstExcelSheet` and cell `A1` containing string `Tester`.

#### See also

See this tutorial on [Apache POI – Reading and Writing Excel file in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/).

Comment: I see, I thought that if I need to use the instance data (file path) from another class (ExcelReader, in the same package), I will have to make extend the class and make it to be a subclass thus I can use the instance data from it.

Comment: I also wonder that if I want the program to group the same group of Strings (compare strings), but the only thing I can give is the column in excel file, is it possible to do that? I know that this seems confusing, I will explain it more detail if needed, but please do help me with it because I am stuck with it for a long time, thank you very much.

Comment: @FlashSonic526 (1) Understood but need the full code of class `ExcelReader` see comment to your question. (2) Don't understand: `group the same group of Strings (compare strings)`. Maybe __add an example__ to your question, __better: ask in a new question__ and link both questions :-)

Comment: but the problem still does occur after removing `extend ExcelReader`, I put the file path directly to `workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\book1.xls`, it doesn't work, I put the link and store it into a  constant String and use it, it still doesn't work, please do help me.

Comment: I updated the entire stack trace, did not see anything that does has `Caused by:` but I updated the whoe stack trace, please take a look, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204959/discussion-between-hc-dev-and-flashsonic526).

Answer (score 0):

Because putting this in the comment would not be feasible. Could you try to remove this portion of code in the pom.xml and try it again?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

based on cursory reading. it has been defined in the bellow code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I supposed that you meant removing poi-ooxml 3.11 dependency, and keep poi-ooxml 4.1.1 dependency?

Comment: yes. that's right :) seems like the field itself is not exists in 3.11 version

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I need some clarifying, what you meant "the field itself is not exists in 3.11 version", do you mean that by removing the `<dependency>` only or remove the `.jar` file and dependency? Thanks.

Comment: what I mean is you need to remove the `<dependency>` tag. and afterward, you need to "package" your application again to ensure the aforementioned dependency has been removed from your `jar` file (so, by that extension, it would also remove the `.jar` file).

Comment: Thanks for your information, but just to let you know that since I do not know much about java and I only have 4 months experience with it, therefore, the dependency file was created by creating a new file in the `lib` folder and change the file type to `.pom`, so does these steps automatically add a "`<dependency>` tab" to the package?

Comment: well, it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

The only apache-poi dependencies you need in pom.xml are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please remove others.

When I removed the others, my code worked.